# From moment generating function to probability function (two variables)

Tags: probability-theory

## Problem

The moment generating function of X is
$\psi(t,u)=exp(t^2+3tu+4u^2)$. Find it's probability density function.

This is a question from Gut - An intermediate course in probability. Ch5E5.2

## Attempt 1

$\int_{all \, u}\psi(t,u)du=\psi(t)$ and then we can "recognize" it, perhaps as a normal distr.

## Attempt 2

This is very non mathy. But I do  $\psi(t,u)=exp(4u^2+ut3/2)exp(t^2+3/2tu)$ then I thought I could recognize the normal moment generation function $$e^{t\mu + (\sigma t)^2 /2}$$ and conclude that variance of X_1 is 2 and variance of X_2 is 8. But this is *so* wrong.

## Question

A bit of guidance toward the solution would be good. My attempts are not very thought through.

Comment: Just to doublecheck: why does the MGF function have 2 arguments?

Comment: @YuliaV X is a 2x1 vector.

Answer (score 3):

I think you may proceed as follows: Let $\psi_T(t)$ be the mgf of T

$$
\psi_T(t)= \psi_{T,U}(t,0)=e^{t^2}
$$
Therefore, $T \sim N(0,2)$

$$
\psi_U(u)= \psi_{T,U}(0,u)=e^{4u^2}
$$
Therefore, $U \sim N(0,8)$

Now, to find the covariance between the two variables:
$$
Cov(T,U)=\Bbb E[TU]-\Bbb E[T] \Bbb E[U]=\Bbb E[TU]\\=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{du}\Bbb E[e^{tT+uU}] \bigg\vert_{u=t=0}=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{du}e^{t^2+3tu+4u^2} \bigg\vert_{u=t=0}
$$
This is an example of a jointly gaussian rv, after finding the covariance, you may find the PDF of a jointly gaussian rv and fit it to this case. See the first line of page 2 here for example : https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece461/handouts/notes1.pdf

hope this helps

Comment: with $u=v=0$ I guess you mean $u=t=0$.

Comment: I don't understand why $$\Bbb E[TU]=\frac{d}{dt}\frac{d}{du}\Bbb E[e^{tT+uU}]\bigg\vert_{u=t=0}$$ Is it a theorem or obvious?

Comment: My first thought was to attack it with the defn of expected value, and we know T and U is Normal and their variances. So I can use the PDF

$$    f(x,y) =
      \frac{1}{2 \pi  \sigma_x \sigma_y \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}
      \exp\left(
        -\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left[
          \frac{(x-\mu_x)^2}{\sigma_x^2} +
          \frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{\sigma_y^2} -
          \frac{2\rho(x-\mu_x)(y-\mu_y)}{\sigma_x \sigma_y}
        \right]
      \right),
 $$
But then I was a bit stuck since I don't know $\rho$.

Comment: @jacob, see the section on 'cross moments' in the following link: 
http://www.statlect.com/subon2/momgen2.htm

this is similar to saying the expected value of a rv is the derivative of the mgf evaluated at zero. and yes now that you have the covariance, finding $\rho$ is very easy to do!

Comment: "the expected value of a rv is the derivative of the mgf evaluated at zero" damn I knes it 1 variable case, just didn't see it in two variables here. thanks. So my goal is to 1) find $\rho$ then 2 plug it into $f(x,y)$ and see something.

Comment: yes, so in this case covariance is 3, use the fact that $\rho=\frac{COV(U,T)}{\sigma_T\sigma_U}$ which gives a value of approximately 0.6. You now have all the info for the pdf. Please upvote and tick the answer if you found it useful!

Comment: I get $\rho^2=9/16^2$ so the $\sqrt{1-\rho^2}$ is $\sqrt{247/256}$ I can't make it look pretty and thereby recognizing something.

Comment: COV(T,U) = 3, $ \rho= \frac{3}{\sqrt{8} \sqrt{2}}=\frac{3}{4}$ therefore $\rho^2=\frac{9}{16}$ ... Im not really sure what your point is..?

Comment: also note that $2\pi \sigma_T\sigma_U (1-\rho^2)$ can be rewritten as:
$$
2\pi \sqrt{8} \sqrt{2}\sqrt{1-\frac{9}{16}}\\
2\pi \sqrt{8} \sqrt{2} \sqrt{\frac{7}{16}}\\
=\pi \sqrt{7}
$$

Comment: forgot a square root sign but hopefully you get the gist of it